# Is there any other function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

$ \forall $ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ We know that the most trivial functions satisfying the functional equation

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$

as $f(x)=a^x$, $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$.

Are there any other functions

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38376/classifying-functions-of-the-form-fxy-fxfy.

Comment: @anurag $f$ need not be continous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all functions $f$, defined over real numbers that satisfy $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735508/find-all-functions-f-defined-over-real-numbers-that-satisfy-fxy-fxf)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: The only solution to that is the trivial one, which is explicitly excluded in this question.

Comment: Oop, my bad then @user21820

Answer (score 1):

That is *not* an easy question.

Consider a function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and define $f=e^g$. Then, clearly, $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. So, are there functions like $g$ other than those defined by $g(x)=cx$, for some real $c$? Well, [it's complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). Basically, it depends upon which set theory you are working with.